# 64 Bit P/Invoke Idiosyncrasy

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, pinvoke

I am trying to properly Marshal some structs for a P/Invoke, but am finding strange behavior when testing on a 64 bit OS.

I have a struct defined as:

```
/// <summary>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366870(v=VS.85).aspx</summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MIB_IPNETTABLE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwNumEntries;
    public IntPtr table; //MIB_IPNETROW[]
}
```

Now, to get the address of the table, I would like to do a Marshal.OffsetOf() call like so:

```
IntPtr offset = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETTABLE), "table");
```

This should be 4 - I have dumped the bytes of the buffer to confirm this as well as replacing the above call with a hard coded 4 in my pointer arithmetic, which yielded correct results.

I do get the expected 4 if I instantiate MIB_IPNETTABLE and perform the following call:

```
IntPtr offset = (IntPtr)Marshal.SizeOf(ipNetTable.dwNumEntries);
```

Now, in a sequential struct the offset of a field should be sum of the sizes of preceding fields, correct?  Or is it the case that when it is an unmanaged structure the offset really is 8 (on an x64 system), but becomes 4 only after Marshalling magic?  Is there a way to get the OffsetOf() call to give me the correct offset?  I can limp along using calls to SizeOf(), but OffsetOf() is simpler for larger structs.

Comment: That struct is translated incorrectly. In fact `table` in an inline array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a 64-bit C/C++ build the offset of your `table` field would be 8 due to alignment requirements (unless you forced it otherwise).  I suspect that the CLR is doing the same to you:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx

> The members of the object are laid out sequentially, in the order in which they appear when 
>   exported to unmanaged memory. The members are laid out according to the packing specified in `StructLayoutAttribute.Pack`, and can be noncontiguous.

you may wnat to use that attribute or use the `LayoutKind.Explicit` attribute along with the `FieldOffset` attribute on each field if you need that level of control.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions on unmanaged alignment.  Explicit Layout with FieldOffset is what I am looking for.