# Calculate padding of unmanaged table

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, pinvoke

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for MIB_IPNETTABLE say:

> **The MIB_IPNETTABLE structure may contain padding for alignment** between
>   the dwNumEntries member and the first MIB_IPNETROW array entry in the
>   table member. Padding for alignment **may also be present between the
>   MIB_IPNETROW array entries** in the table member. Any access to a
>   MIB_IPNETROW array entry should assume padding may exist.

Will

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETROW))
```

Take care of that? If not - how do I know how much padding exists in order to account for it. If yes - will it work on x64 without a problem (See [64 Bit P/Invoke Idiosyncrasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903510/64-bit-p-invoke-idiosyncrasy) )?

Comment: That documentation remark makes no sense to me. I cannot see where any padding could come from.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A) Thanks. B) According to the link in the last line of the question - It actually happens. (At least according to the answer there.)

Comment: That question is misleading. I left a comment there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think you meant "table **is** an inline array" in the comment there. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Since .NET 4.5.1 you can write `Marshal.SizeOf<MIB_IPNETROW>()` instead of `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETROW))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of both `MIB_IPNETROW` and `MIB_IPNETTABLE` on x86 and x64 is 4. That can be deduced by looking at the alignment of the struct members. And as for the array, there will be no padding between elements because there never is padding between array elements.

Hence there will be no padding at all on those platforms, and indeed the layout is the same on both platforms.

I cannot explain why the documentation talks of padding. Perhaps on Alpha or Itanium there would be padding, but not on x86 and x64. Or perhaps the documentation is just wrong.

Comment: I understand that there _is_ no padding. However, in cases where there is padding (if it exists on Itanium / in other structs) - how _can_ that be handled - How can we know what bytes to skip?

Comment: In order to answer that there would need to be some understanding of why padding would exist. I see no reason why padding would exist anywhere. I think the documentation is just wrong.